# How to load Html from string to webview on android

Tags: java, android, html, webview, runtime-error

For my learning purposes as a begginer
I want to make an app that can load a webpage using html code.
I used this code (I copied from yt Tutorial)

```
webview1.load(myHtmlString, 
"text/html",  null);
```

When I try to run the app
it says its an error

The method load(string, string, null) is undefined for the type webview

Answer (score 3):

Try using UTF-8 format like this

```
mWebView.loadData(myHtmlString, "text/html", "UTF-8");
```

**OR**

if your **sdk targeting 29** it recomended to using base64 to avoid not loaded on your webview

```
String encodedHtml = Base64.encodeToString(myHtmlString.getBytes(), Base64.NO_PADDING);

mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

mWebView.loadData(encodedHtml, "text/html", "base64");
```

Comment: Its error again the type Base64 is ambigous

Comment: did you using this import `import android.util.Base64;` ?